# Flex client for java socket server

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, sockets

I created my own java socket server that doesn't do websocket just plain old socket. I had every message wrapped inside 0x00 and 0xFF. So every message starts with 0x00 and ends with 0xFF. For some reason when I read it from flash once in a while when message size exceed 3000 bytes i get garballed message or message missing a character or incomplete message. This is what I have in flash. Any pointer on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
private function onData(event:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            var obj:String;

            while(_serviceSocket.bytesAvailable > 0)
            {
                if(_serviceSocket.readByte() == START_FRAME || _currentBuffer == null)
                {
                    _currentBuffer = new ByteArray();
                }
                var byte:int;
                while(true)
                {           
                    try
                    {
                        byte = _serviceSocket.readByte();
                        if(byte == END_FRAME){
                            obj = _currentBuffer.toString();
                            processMessage(obj);
                            _currentBuffer = null;
                            break;
                        }else{
                            _currentBuffer.writeByte(byte);                             
                        }
                    }catch(e:Error){
                        obj = _currentBuffer.toString();
                        processMessage(obj);
                        _currentBuffer = null;
                        break;
                    }                       
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the error ?

Comment: There is no error but when I look at the bytes I receive they are not in order, causing messages to to miss a character or portion. This only happens in production environment, I can't duplicate in my box.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and check for the output

```
function onData(event:ProgressEvent):void{

    var data:String = "";

    var stream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    socket.writeBytes(stream, 0, 0);

    while(socket.bytesAvailable){
        data += socket.readUTFBytes(1);
    }

    trace("data "+ data);   

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wish I could duplicate this in my box, I have been running the server and hammering it with request for few hours now and I have not been able to recreate it. I noted your readUTFBytes, let see if that helps.

Comment: Why do you send a empty `ByteArray` to socket? can you explain that?